# JavaFX 2 modal window

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm trying to create a login window with JavaFX 2 and stop execution until the user has not logged. I want something like the below:

```
showLoginDialog();
showMainWindow();
```

`showLoginDialog` is responsible for creating a new stage and set its parent to be the main window. It sets the stage to be modal, I tried both `WINDOW_MODAL` and `APPLICATION_MODAL`, but as soon as the login window is showed, the `showMainWindow()` line is called as well.

Is it possible to stop code running until the `close()` of the login stage is called, or something similar? Are there any tutorials showing how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Uluk said there is a JIRA issue. The issue has been closed and fixed in version 2.2 beta of JavaFX. 
Just use the following code if execution of the program needs to be stopped:

```
modalWindowStage.showAndWait();
```

where `modalWindowStage` is the stage used for showing the messagebox.
If the execution needs to continue, just use the usual 'show()' method.

Answer (score 3):

Jira issue exists for this http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19783.
Until that time you can call `showMainWindow();` in an action of login button.

Comment: Didn't know about the issue. That is what i'm doing at the moment. Thank you a lot for the answer :)