# How to create a modal window in JavaFX 2.1

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I can't figure out how to create a modal window in JavaFX. Basically I have file chooser and I want to ask the user a question when they select a file. I need this information in order to parse the file, so the execution needs to wait for the answer.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008377/javafx-2-modal-window) but I've not been able to find out how to implement this behavior.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is [link to a solution](https://gist.github.com/1887631) I created earlier for modal dialogs in JavaFX 2.1
The solution creates a modal stage on top of the current stage and takes action on the dialog results via event handlers for the dialog controls.

## JavaFX 8+

The prior linked solution uses a dated event handler approach to take action after a dialog was dismissed.  That approach was valid for pre-JavaFX 2.2 implementations.  For JavaFX 8+ there is no need for event handers, instead, use the new Stage [`showAndWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) method.  For example:

```
Stage dialog = new Stage();

// populate dialog with controls.
...

dialog.initOwner(parentStage);
dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
dialog.showAndWait();

// process result of dialog operation. 
...
```

Note that, in order for things to work as expected, it is important to initialize the owner of the Stage *and* to initialize the modality of the Stage to either [WINDOW_MODAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#WINDOW_MODAL) or [APPLICATION_MODAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#APPLICATION_MODAL).

There are some high quality standard UI dialogs in [JavaFX 8](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) and [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/), if they fit your requirements, I advise using those rather than developing your own.  Those in-built JavaFX [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) and [Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) classes also have [`initOwner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) and [`initModality`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initModality-javafx.stage.Modality-) and [`showAndWait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#showAndWait--) methods, so that you can set the modality for them as you wish (note that, by default, the in-built dialogs are application modal).

Comment: ControlsFX library has been developed for JavaFX version 8.0 and above, to be released in Q1 2014, so one must take it into consideration.

Comment: @jewelsea is there any filechooser function for javafx 1.3?

Comment: Avinash, it is best to ask a new question as a new question.  JavaFX 1.3 is obsolete, I don't advise using it.  I do not think that it directly had a FileChooser, though you might be able to use a Swing [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) with it.

Answer (score 72):

In my opinion this is not good solution, because parent window is all time active.
For example if You want open window as modal after click button...

```
private void clickShow(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(
        YourClassController.class.getResource("YourClass.fxml"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setTitle("My modal window");
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(
        ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow() );
    stage.show();
}
```

Now Your new window is REALY modal - parent is block.
also You can use

```
Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL
```

Comment: I had to use stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
to block calling parent. Even using showAndWait() did not block the caller (I was calling from a JFXPanel-not sure if that made any difference.)

Answer (score -1):

You can create application like my sample. This is only single file JavaFX application.

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Stage stage; 
                stage = new Stage();

                final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

                createSwingContent(swingNode);

                StackPane pane = new StackPane();
                pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 250, 150));
                stage.show();
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
                String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(s + "/src/reports/report1.jrxml");

                String query = "SELECT * FROM `accounttype`";
                JRDesignQuery jrquery = new JRDesignQuery();
                jrquery.setText(query);
                jasperDesign.setQuery(jrquery);

                JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
                JasperPrint JasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, c);
                //JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(JasperPrint);

                swingNode.setContent(new JRViewer(JasperPrint));
            } catch (JRException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AccountTypeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might improve the quality of your answer if you added an explanation of what about your answer you think will help and why.