# No errors, but crashing - JOptionPane - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, joptionpane, println

I am trying to get a pop-up message when the cake node is clicked on. It prints to the console, but "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Test");" crashes the program when I click on the cake (no errors). Any ideas?

```
class Cake extends Item {

double dx=3,dy=1.6;

Cake(String imageFile, double x, double y) {
    super(imageFile, x, y);
}


@Override
public void move() {
    this.setX(this.getX()+dx);

    if(this.getX()>749 || this.getX()<-20) {
        dx=-dx;
    }

    this.setY(this.getY()+dy);

    if(this.getY()>530 || this.getY()<0) {
        dy=-dy;
    }


}


@Override
public void collision() {
    //System.out.println("Cake");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Test");


}

}
```

Comment: Have you already read this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108927/joptionpane-in-javafx-making-window-not-respond)

Comment: But note that since that was written, JavaFX introduced a [Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) class.

Comment: I think instead of `null` there should be a stage

Comment: Umm, no. Don't mix Swing and FX.

Comment: Okay, I read the following [link](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) and they use other classes for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Swing's `JOptionPane` in a JavaFX application. Use [`Dialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), or in this case an [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) instead:

```
@Override
public void collision() {
    //System.out.println("Cake");

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setHeaderText("Test");
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```