# how to disable a javafx window

Tags: java, javafx

I have this situation, I'm creating a new stage and new scene in every occurrence!

a new stage and new scene is created from a button on the scene, I want to disable the first scene  when the new scene is active.

Comment: Why not just make the new stage modal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a modal window in JavaFX 2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486731/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-javafx-2-1)