# Locking Modal window called from the FXMLController

Tags: java, javafx, modal-dialog

I'm having a JavaFX-GUI that enables the user to scan. 
This process is taking a while. So the user should neither keep clicking around, nor should anyone think the program hung itself.

My solution was a modal window that is just in front of the whole GUI and and disappears itself when everything is finished.

The interface consists of a FXML-Controller, the FXML-File and the MainApp.

So far I'm calling it in the Controller:

```
Stage stage = Messages.beforeScan(event);    
s.scan(filename);
stage.close();
```

The `beforeScan`-Method looks like that (Taken from [How to create a modal window in JavaFX 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486731/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-javafx-2-1) ):

```
public static Stage beforeScan(Event event) {
        Stage stage = new Stage(); 
        try {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(
                    FXMLController.class.getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.setTitle("My modal window");
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Meldungen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return stage;
    }
```

Yet this is not successful. If I comment out `stage.close();` I can still use my main GUI.
So a different approach:
Instead of importing the Scene from the controller I tired to obtain it from the MainApp-Class:

```
public static Stage beforeScan(Event event) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

            stage.setScene(MainApp.getStage.getScene());
            stage.setTitle("My modal window");
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            stage.show();

        return stage;
    }
```

But this just crashes everything with a `StackOverflow`.
The Popup (Taken from the example [here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1926196) ) is not helpful either. It is even only opened after the scan.

Using an Alert seemed like a good idea, but doing it that way is not only locking the screen but the program itself:

```
public Alert beforeScan(Event event) {
       javafx.scene.control.Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE, "Scan in progress");

       alert.showAndWait();
       return alert;
    }
```

How should a screen-locking modal window/popup be done properly?

Comment: Either you're modifying the UI in from a thread other than the application thread or you're running a long-running task on the application thread blocking it. Either way you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @fabian - any suggestions what I _should_ do?

Comment: Show the stage, run the long-running task on a different thread and at the end of it use `Platform.runLater` to close the stage...

Comment: @fabian - frankly I don't get the part with the `Platform.runLater`. I made Scan runnable and used `Thread thread = new Thread(s);
                        thread.start();
                        thread.join();` Before that I start the dialog and after it I close it. How should the `runLater` be implemented? And how do I make sure the GUI is locked?

Comment: Why do you even start a new thread if you call `join` immediately? I thought of something like this: `stage.show(); new Thread(() -> {  try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} Platform.runLater(stage::close); }).start();` (Replace `Thread.sleep()`+`try-catch` with your long running task.)