# JAVAFX - Create a new Window

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a new window activated from a button, however while this new window was open, the main window can not be used.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initModality-javafx.stage.Modality-

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Stage s1 = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        s1.setScene(scene);
        s1.show();


This code is in an OnAction function of a button, the main window (where the button is) can not be used while this new window is open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a modal window in JavaFX 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486731/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-javafx-2-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When create new stage and add required objects to it add:

```
    newStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    newStage.showAndWait();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make your new `Stage newStage` you have to set the other window as it's owner and then set it to be window modal.

```
newStage.initOwner(parentStage);
newStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

Comment: in my code of using `primaryStage` in the `start()` method, it turns out that `newStage.initOwner(parentStage)` did not really help of getting the output. not sure if it is due to my computer's settings