# JavaFX 2.2 Modal window dialog *with* FXML

Tags: modal-dialog, javafx-2, fxml

I am trying to use the example provided by @jewelsea [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/1887631) and I'm stuck because I'm using FXML.

I have seen both of these posts: [How to create a modal window in JavaFX 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486731/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-javafx-2-1) and [this answer to JavaFX 2 modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494886/492404).

Where I'm stuck is in the code by jewelsea, where it says:

```
final WebView webView = new WebView(); 
webView.getEngine().load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
```

Whereas, since I'm using FXML, I do this:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyFXML.fxml"));
Scene scene = (Scene)fxmlLoader.load();
myController = fxmlLoader.getController();
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

Can you tell me how to modify my code (the 4 lines above), so it works with jewelsea's example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement code you are using via `FXMLLoader` rather than the `WebView` created scene sample code is fine, you don't need to modify it.

Your code will display the main scene for your primary stage based on an fxml document (for my sample I was using a WebView as my main scene, which you don't need, so you don't need any of the WebView related code from the gist).

What you need is some trigger in your controller at the time you want to display a dialog.  As a simple example, you can setup an fxml for your main scene which just includes a button, and then supply an ActionHandler for the button in your controller (just like in the [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) document).

Now, instead of just doing a println when the button is pressed as Introduction to FXML has, call the `dialog.show()` method like the gist did at the time of WebView document load.  What should happen is that the dialog will now be displayed on top of your fxml generated scene.

You will notice that the dialog itself contains a Scene.  If you wanted (and this is optional), you could define the scene contents using fxml.  To do this, at the time of dialog construction, you set up a new fxml and new controller for the dialog contents and load the fxml created scene for the dialog into the dialog's stage.  The code to do this is pretty much identical code to what you used to load the main scene's fxml into the primaryStage.

Try the above and see if it works for you.  If you are still stuck I can probably create an fxml specific example of the gist along the lines of this answer.

Also note that the referenced gist was written a while ago, and there is a now a [showAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait%28%29) method in JavaFX which facilitates blocking execution of code when making a dialog call and then allowing to process the result of the dialog without using some of the event handler mechanisms from the gist example.  Strategies both with and without showAndWait are perfectly acceptable solutions though.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I almost have it integrated, the only place where I'm still stuck is I'm not sure how best to pass a reference to the `dialog` variable into my controller, in order to then call `dialog.showAndWait();` on it--in my handler in the controller manipulating my `primaryStage` scene, created via FXML. I even tried (unsuccessfully) to create a dummy <Scene fx:id="dialog" /> in the main scene FXML file I'm using (w/corresponding `@FXML Stage dialog;` declaration in controller).  Any further advice?  (The approach I'm using is *not* to use FXML w/dialog, just for my main scene.)

Comment: I've looked around quite a bit, but can't find any tutorials that cover how to do 'regular' (non-FXML) JavaFX code after creating a main controller using FXML.  I don't think this dialog deserves a whole separate FXML file, controller, etc. (it's just a warning, doing some actions, before proceeding with my main stage).  So any help on how to get a reference to my `dialog` object?  Thanks again.

Comment: Here is a [temporary link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/baanthaispa/ConfirmationDialog.zip) to a NetBeans Project which includes a sample of an fxml page launching a non-FXML based dialog.

Comment: Wow.  Extensive.  Thank you!  Appreciate all your help.  (I believe there's a copy/paste typo in getSide--from setSide, but looks great otherwise.)